# How to add input prompts to SharePoint 2013 Form Fields

Tags: 2013, input, formfield

What I'd like to do is add input prompts to text fields on a Sharepoint 2013 form.

There's a fairly nice solution [here](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/input-prompt-text/), and it does the mechanics nicely. What it shows for a prompt, however, is the underlying textarea title, which is rendered as the field's NAME. Unfortunately, the SharePoint:FormField control doesn't expose the title attribute.

If I could get it to render the field's DESCRIPTION instead, I'd have exactly what I want.

Does anyone here know how to do this?

TIA
Josh

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery('input[type=text][title],input[type=password][title],textarea[title]').each(function(i){
    jQuery(this).addClass('input-prompt-' + i);
    var promptSpan = jQuery('<span class="input-prompt"/>');
    jQuery(promptSpan).attr('id', 'input-prompt-' + i);     
    jQuery(promptSpan).append(jQuery(this).parent().next().html());
    jQuery(promptSpan).click(function(){
        jQuery(this).hide();
        jQuery('.' + jQuery(this).attr('id')).focus();
    });
    if(jQuery(this).val() != ''){
        jQuery(promptSpan).hide();
    }
    jQuery(this).before(promptSpan);
    jQuery(this).focus(function(){
        jQuery('#input-prompt-' + i).hide();
    });
    jQuery(this).blur(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).val() == ''){
            jQuery('#input-prompt-' + i).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Amal, you're rehashing the Kyle Schaeffer code I'm already using (see "here" above). The prompt appears and disappears appropriately, but it uses the NAME of the field rather than its DESCRIPTION

Comment: Yes. I modified the code so now it pull description instead.

Comment: It doesn't work. The expression

    <b>$(this).parent().next().html()</b>

is undefined. And looking at the generated markup, the code would have to come from the server - how else could it pick up the description field (which isn't otherwise rendered)?

Comment: In 2013 description is placed below the input controls

Comment: Only on out-of-box edit forms.

Comment: To some degree, it's possible to do the same thing in a custom designed form by placing SharePoint:FieldDescription controls immediately after the FormField controls, but the jquery code also works on date fields (which you don't want it to tinker with) and such, creating something of a mess of the form.